error when i add custom Theme at Keycloak with helm chart
i trying to add to my pod the theme with helm chart  i want that he pull from my github repo the jar file and mount it at /opt/bitname/keyclaok/provides
Values :

initContainers: "- name: realm-ext-provider\n  image: curlimages/curl\n  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent\n  command:\n    - sh\n  args:\n    - -c\n    - |\n      # Replace USER and PROJECT.    \n      curl -L -f -S -o /extensions/custom_themes.jar \"https://github/user/project/path/custom_themes.jar\"\n      #magic___^_^___line\n  volumeMounts:\n    - name: extensions\n      mountPath: /extensions\n      #magic___^_^___line\n"

extraVolumeMounts: |
  - name: extensions
    mountPath: /opt/bitnami/keycloak/providers

extraVolumes: |
  - name: extensions
    emptyDir: {}

the initcontainers is completed
the pod is crashing
the error log:
keycloak ERROR: Failed to run 'build' command.                                                                                                                                             │
│ keycloak ERROR: java.io.IOException: Failed to create a new filesystem for /opt/bitnami/keycloak/lib/../providers/custom_themes.jar                                                        │
│ keycloak ERROR: Failed to create a new filesystem for /opt/bitnami/keycloak/lib/../providers/custom_themes.jar                                                                             │
│ keycloak ERROR: zip END header not found                                                                                                                                                   │
│ keycloak For more details run the same command passing the '--verbose' option. Also you can use '--help' to see the details about the usage of the particular command.  ```

anyone knows how to fix it ? 

i follow this guide :

https://docs.keycloakify.dev/keycloak-configuration/importing-your-theme-in-keycloak


IMO, the error message zip END header not found suggests that the JAR file might be corrupted or not properly downloaded.

Check your file permissions and the Keycloack process has the right permissions to read your jar.
Make sure the curl command is correctly run by adding ls -l /extensions
Use a different image image: alpine:latest and install curl using curl apk add --no-cache curl

